# Google Maps client side geocoding cost

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We all know that google has enforced limit of 25000 impressions per IP. In this article
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat
They say that if the geocoding is entirely client based i.e just use Javascript to load whatever in client side this limit scales to 25000 impressions per user session. So unless you are geocoding from server side you should still be able to use maps for free right?
For example consider an application where you have a few coordinates and you need to show those coordinates as markers in google map. This sort of application would require
no assistance from server and can be done entirely on client's side. So unless a user makes more than 25000 impressions a day you are safe. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. AFAIK the 25k limit is from loading the JS-Api per user. It has nothing to do with reverse geocode or massive waypoint and direction requests. A good example is the travelsalesman problem. With small number of cities 20 you need to request lots of directions 20!.